# Recombee batch does not send all the data

Tags: django, recommendation-engine

I am using recombees API for a recommendation and there is a batch method to send all the user data to the API.
The code for the following:

```
for i in range(0,len(list_of_ratings)):
    name = str(list_of_ratings[i].user)
    series = str(list_of_ratings[i].series)
    rate = list_of_ratings[i].rating
    print(name + ' ' + series + ' ' + str(rate))
    request = AddRating(name, series, rate ,cascade_create=True)
    requests.append(request)

try:    
    client.send(Batch(requests))
except APIException as e:
    print(e) 
except ResponseException as e:
    print(e)
except ApiTimeoutException as e:
    print(e)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

But the problem is it does not send all the data. There are 946 data objects that I have in a Django model but the first time when i ran this only 20 were sent and during the 2nd time only 6.
I dont know whats causing the issue.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide sample output which gets printed based on `list_of_ratings`?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps there is some error in your batch. I would suggest printing the batch result to see eventual error messages:

```
res = client.send(Batch(requests))
print(res)
```